# C'est du piment rouge or C'est un piment rouge?

Tags: grammaire, partitif

The other day I was reading a French comic when I noticed one of the characters said this:

> Vous mentez! C'est **du** piment rouge!

Note the use of the partitive. This strikes me as a little odd, since I would think red peppers would be countable (like bananas, for instance). Shouldn't it be

> C'est **un** piment rouge!

instead? I'm not a native French speaker, so I'm not entirely certain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"C'est un piment rouge" implies that you are speaking about a whole red pepper whereas "C'est du piment rouge" implies a more vague amount of pepper.

It's the equivalent of "It's red pepper" vs "It's a red pepper".

Comment: All right, thanks. At first when I saw this answer I wasn't quite certain why the writer would do this, but after considering the context I can see why (it's rather subtle).

Answer (score 4):

Sur l'étal d'un marché de plein vent, c'est **un** piment rouge.

Au rayon des épices du supermarché, c'est **du** piment rouge.

Answer (score 2):

As a native french speaker, I can assure you that both sentences are correct, although "C'est du piment rouge!" sounds more natural to me.